# GROUP BY in subquery T-SQL

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, group-by, subquery

I am trying to make a table like this:

> ProductName |  SalesByDate |  TotalSalesUntilDate
>
> ```
>     A     |      5    |      15
>
>     B     |     10    |      30
>
>     C     |     20    |      25
>
>     D     |     18    |      43
> ```

SalesByDate means the number of product sold for each product on the input date and TotalSalesUntilDate indicates the number of product sold for each product from the first date of the month until the input date (example of input date: 17 March 2010)

I wrote this query using subquery:

```
    select p.ProductName, A.SalesByDate,
      (select(SUM(case when (pd.Date between '01' and @Date) 
      then s.SalesByDate else 0 end)) 
    from Period pd 
    inner join Sales s on pd.TimeID = s.TimeID 
    full join Product p on s.ProductID = p.ProductID) as TotalSalesUntilDate 
    from Product p join 
         (select s.ProductID, pd.Date, s.SalesByDate
          from Period pd join Sales s on pd.TimeID = s.TimeID) A on 
    p.ProductID = A.ProductID where @Date = A.Date
```

but I got the result:

> ProductName   |     SalesByDate |  TotalSalesUntilDate
>
> ```
>      A    |     5     |      113
>
>      B    |    10     |      113
>
>      C    |    20     |      113
>
>      D    |    18     |      113
> ```

which the TotalSalesUntilDate shows the number of product sold from the first date of the month until the input date but for all product without separation for each product.

So when I tried to change the query to like this (adding GROUP BY p.ProductID before "as TotalSalesUntilDate"):

```
   select p.ProductName, A.SalesByDate,
     (select(SUM(case when (pd.Date between '01' and @Date) 
     then s.SalesByDate else 0 end)) 
   from Period pd 
     inner join Sales s on pd.TimeID = s.TimeID 
     full join Product p on s.ProductID = p.ProductID 
     group by p.ProductID) as TotalSalesUntilDate 
  from Product p join 
     (select s.ProductID, pd.Date, s.SalesByDate
     from Period pd join Sales s on pd.TimeID = s.TimeID) A on 
    p.ProductID = A.ProductID where @Date = A.Date
```

and when I execute this query, I got this error message:

> "Msg 512, Level 16, State 1, Procedure SalesMTDSubQuery, Line 7
>   Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the
>   subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= or when the subquery is used as
>   an expression."

Since I'm new in SQL and still learning, but I don't understand how to solve this. Any help will be appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: It would be helpful if you could provide the relevant raw data you are working with so that we can run the query ourselves.  Also what is the purpose of `'01'` in `pd.Date between '01' and @Date`?

Comment: '01' in pd.Date between '01' and @Date is for get the sales quantity from date 01 till the input date (I put the input date in variable @Date) and then SUM them, since I state SUM function there. Oh, I'll provide the raw data then but since the data is too much, maybe I just post a half of it. It's no problem, isn't it?

Comment: @mellamokb I've edited the question by adding the raw data which is from 3 tables. If it's not enough so I've to provide more, let me know. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In  the `@Date` variable we are storing the date:

```
SELECT DISTINCT PT.[ProductName]
      ,SUM(IIF(PD.[Date] = @Date, SL.[SalesByDate], 0)) 
      ,SUM(IIF(PD.[Date] BETWEEN '01' AND @Date, SL.[SalesByDate], 0)) 
FROM @Product PT
INNER JOIN @Sales SL
    ON PT.[ProductID] = SL.[ProductID]
INNER JOIN @Period PD
    ON SL.[TimeID] = PD.[TimeID]
GROUP BY PT.[ProductName]
```

Result:

[image]

Full code:

```
DECLARE @Period TABLE
(
     [TimeID] TINYINT
    ,[Date] CHAR(2)
)

INSERT INTO @Period([TimeID], [Date])
VALUES   (1,'01')
        ,(2,'02')
        ,(3,'03')
        ,(4,'04')
        ,(5,'05')
        ,(6,'06')
        ,(7,'07')
        ,(8,'08')
        ,(9,'09')
        ,(10,'10')
        ,(11,'11')
        ,(12,'12')
        ,(13,'13')
        ,(14,'14')
        ,(15,'15')

DECLARE @Product TABLE
(
     [ProductID] TINYINT
    ,[ProductName] CHAR(1)
)

INSERT INTO @Product( [ProductID], [ProductName])
VALUES (1,'A')
      ,(2,'B')
      ,(3,'C')
      ,(4,'D')

DECLARE @Sales TABLE
(
     [TimeID] TINYINT
    ,[ProductID] TINYINT
    ,[SalesByDate] TINYINT
)

INSERT INTO @Sales ([TimeID], [ProductID], [SalesByDate])
VALUES   (1, 1, 10)
        ,(1, 4, 20)
        ,(7, 2, 10)
        ,(7, 3, 5)
        ,(15, 1, 5)
        ,(15, 2, 10)
        ,(15, 3, 15)
        ,(15, 4, 18)
        ,(19, 2, 15)
        ,(20, 3, 2)
        ,(22, NULL, 2)
        ,(1, 4, 5)
        ,(7, 2, 10)
        ,(15, 3, 5)

DECLARE @Date CHAR(2) = '15'

SELECT DISTINCT PT.[ProductName]
      ,SUM(IIF(PD.[Date] = @Date, SL.[SalesByDate], 0)) 
      ,SUM(IIF(PD.[Date] BETWEEN '01' AND @Date, SL.[SalesByDate], 0)) 
FROM @Product PT
INNER JOIN @Sales SL
    ON PT.[ProductID] = SL.[ProductID]
INNER JOIN @Period PD
    ON SL.[TimeID] = PD.[TimeID]
GROUP BY PT.[ProductName]
```

EDIT:

If you need to use sub-query, this is how your example can works:

```
SELECT PT.[ProductName]
      ,SUM(SL.[SalesByDate])
      ,DataSource.[TotalSalesByDate]
FROM @Product PT
INNER JOIN @Sales SL
    ON PT.[ProductID] = SL.[ProductID]
INNER JOIN @Period PD
    ON SL.[TimeID] = PD.[TimeID]
INNER JOIN 
(
    SELECT S.[ProductID]
          ,SUM(S.[SalesByDate]) AS [TotalSalesByDate]
    FROM @Sales S
    INNER JOIN @Period P
        ON S.[TimeID] = P.[TimeID]
    WHERE P.[Date] BETWEEN '01' AND @Date 
    GROUP BY S.[ProductID] 
) AS DataSource
ON PT.[ProductID] = DataSource.[ProductID]
WHERE PD.[Date] = @Date
GROUP BY PT.[ProductName]
     ,DataSource.[TotalSalesByDate]
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your help. But I have to use subquery for this case, as stated in my lecturer's instruction. :( By the way, what is IIF? Is it the same with IF?

Comment: It is an alternative syntax for a CASE WHEN  - http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh213574.aspx

Comment: Awesome! It works as expected! Thank you gotqn! :) By the way, can u explain why I'm wrong to put the subquery in SELECT statement as written in my query? And when you put it in FROM statement it works fine? I want to know where is my mistake.

Comment: I guess your sub-query `(select s.ProductID, pd.Date, s.SalesByDate
from Period pd join Sales s on pd.TimeID = s.TimeID)` is returning multiple records for some `ProductID` and then in the main query you are trying to display the `SalesByDate` but the server do not know which one to display. In my case, I am doing the `SUM` in the sub-query and I am sure that I will get only one row per `ProductID`

Comment: Umm, so my mistake is about the second subquery which is in FROM statement? Is the first subquery in SELECT statement already correct?

Comment: If I were you,  I will comment the first sub-query in order to check if the error is caused by it. If no, I will try to change the second sub-query in order to ensure one result per `ProductID` is returned.

Comment: Oh,ok. Thanks so much for your advice and solution. :) Ah, I have one more question, are the subqueries have to return only one result, like in this case?

Comment: You are welcome :-) and even you need to use sub-queries it simpler and faster to avoid them in some cases.

Comment: Sorry, I want to ask further, how to display the ProductID but it has NULL value? I've checked your subquery and it returned the NULL value, but since it's inner join on p.ProductID = A.ProductID so the NULL value is ignored. It supposed to be in the result and renamed as 'Unknown'. Is it just about join problem? because I tried to change inner join to right join, left join, and full join but they didn't work.

Answer (score 1):

First, in the `Table Period` you must have dates, not `'01','02'` so you can use `BETWEEN`. Or you can use `1,2,3 ...` but they have to be numbers.

So, we suppose that in table `Table Period` you have numbers for dates (I make this remark, because you use `01`, instead of `1` which assumes string value. The query itself is relatively easy:

```
SELECT 
  p.ProductName, 
  SUM(CASE WHEN s.TimeID = 10 THEN s.SalesByDate ELSE 0 END) as SalesByDate, 
  SUM(CASE WHEN s.TimeID = 10 THEN 0 ELSE s.SalesByDate END) as TotalSalesUntilDate 
FROM 
  Product p 
  INNER JOIN Salse s ON p.ProductID = s.ProductID 
WHERE 
  s.TimeID BETWEEN 1 AND 10
GROUP BY p.ProductName;
```

You take Sales for each date. If this is a selected date then add sales to column `SalesByDate`, else add then to column `TotalSalesUntilDate`. You group by `ProductName` to calculate `SUM`. And select only dates which are in the desired period in `WHERE` clause. We assume that this query is started only for a specific month (because we use only date element - i.e. 1,2,... not month).

This will show only Products with sales. If you want to see all Products list use `LEFT JOIN` instead of `INNER JOIN`.

Comment: Thanks for your help, but I cannot just state when s.TimeID = 10, because the instruction told that the input will be as a date, which is '01', '02', etc instead of TimeID. So for get the sum of sales from '01' and the input date I wrote like that. Or is there any more efficient query I don't know?